# Как открыть поверх основной страницы, дочернюю страницу

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, не переходило на отдельную страницу, а открывалось поверх старой затемняя ее.

Comment: это называется "открыть в модальном окне"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации на **bootstrap 3**. Подробнее смотрите в [документации](http://bootstrap-3.ru/javascript.php#modals)

нажмите выполнить, что бы посмотреть как работает пример.

```html
<!-- подключим jquery и bootstrap 3-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Посмотреть демо</button>

<!-- модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Название модали</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...какой то контент модали...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```